# Error while migrating Webapplication from Tomcat 7.2 to Weblogic 10.3

Tags: web-services

I am getting error when deploying my Web service application on Weblogic 10.3.4.

I have changed the web app version from 3.0 to 2.5 since it is not supported in Weblogic 10.3 version.

Getting the below Exception when deploying the application:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.SpringBinding#0' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]: Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)' of type [org.jvnet.jax_ws_commons.spring.SpringService] while setting bean property 'service'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.xml.ws.server.EndpointFactory.verifyImplementorClass(Ljava/lang/Class;Lcom/sun/xml/ws/api/databinding/MetadataReader;)Z
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:282)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:126)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1387)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:626)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
at com.oracle.weblogic.wsee.wrapper.org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(Unknown Source)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:481)
at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager.notifyContextCreatedEvent(EventsManager.java:181)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1872)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3153)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1508)
at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:482)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:636)
at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:205)
at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:43)
at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activate(BasicDeployment.java:184)
at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.BasicDeployment.activateFromServerLifecycle(BasicDeployment.java:361)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter$1.doActivate(DeploymentAdapter.java:51)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentAdapter.activate(DeploymentAdapter.java:200)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.AppTransition$2.transitionApp(AppTransition.java:30)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.transitionApps(ConfiguredDeployments.java:240)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.activate(ConfiguredDeployments.java:169)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.ConfiguredDeployments.deploy(ConfiguredDeployments.java:123)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.resume(DeploymentServerService.java:180)
at weblogic.management.deploy.internal.DeploymentServerService.start(DeploymentServerService.java:96)
at weblogic.t3.srvr.SubsystemRequest.run(SubsystemRequest.java:64)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:207)
at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:176)
```

WEb. Xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!--  <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">  --> 
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
                             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" 
         id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
  <display-name>SpringWS</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>jaxws-servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
                      com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSSpringServlet
                </servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jaxws-servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/jaxws-spring</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
  </web-app>
```

Spring Config Contents is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:ws="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core"
       xmlns:wss="http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
       http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
       http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/core 
       http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/core.xsd
       http://jax-ws.dev.java.net/spring/servlet 
       http://jax-ws.java.net/spring/servlet.xsd">




    <wss:binding url="/jaxws-spring">
        <wss:service>
           <ws:service bean="#multipleResponseWS"/> 

        </wss:service>
    </wss:binding>
```

Comment: Code snippet of Spring Configuration is

Answer (score 0):

Issue was resolved after specifying below snippet in weblogic.xml

```
  <wls:container-descriptor>
    <wls:prefer-application-packages>
        <wls:package-name>com.sun.xml.ws.server</wls:package-name>
    </wls:prefer-application-packages>
    </wls:container-descriptor>
```